# iOS Vision Face landmarks always returns value

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get the face landmarks using `VNFaceObservation` `iOS Vision API`.

But I noticed even if my eyes or nose are not visible it is returning all the coordinates. I am doing something wrong ?

I make a call to check if left eye is visible something like this which is never `null`, even if I have hidden my eyes.

```
if(observations[0].Landmarks.LeftEye != null)
{
}
```

Comment: Which coordinates does it return when they should not be visible?

Comment: Well I didn't mapped it to check that , but I was expecting it to return null when I have hidden my left eye @DennisSchröer

Comment: Okay, I never worked with this API but it might be that LeftEye has a property which returns true of false depending on if it's visible or not, or the coordinates are manipulated in a way which makes it obvious that it's not visible. Maybe that helps